# How use --config with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, json, phantomjs, casperjs

I've read the Casper documentation and they say that ALL PhantonJS cli options is available on CasperJS but I am trying to use --config=/path/to/config.json and is not working.

Is there a way to fix this or do something similar since I don't want to be editing the configs on terminal.

```
casperjs --config=config.json test.js
```

My config.json file:

```
{
    "load-images" : false
}
```

My test.js file:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://www.example.com/', function(){
    this.capture('image.png');
})

.run();
```

That code above is loading the images. Of course this is a simple example and what I want to is manage lots of options inside the config file.

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate? What is not working or how is it not working? What is the error message?

Comment: Hi, I've added more information on the post. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This issue](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11775) shows the inconsistencies:

```
--disk-cache => diskCacheEnabled
--load-images => autoLoadImages
--local-storage-path => offlineStoragePath
--local-storage-quota => offlineStorageDefaultQuota
--local-to-remote-url-access => localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled
--web-security => webSecurityEnabled
--debug => printDebugMessages
```

But [`autoLoadImages` is broken](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11776). I just verified that `webSecurityEnabled` works as expected.

PhantomJS version 1.9.7.

---

A workaround would be to include the following code in every test file:

```
if (casper.cli.has("config2")) {
    var config = require(casper.cli.get("config2"));
    casper.options.pageSettings.loadImages = config.autoLoadImages;
}
```

and call it with the other command line flag

```
casperjs --config=config.json --config2=config.json test.js
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about these inconsistencies.

Comment: Me neither. I added a workaround, but I don't think it will help much.