# How to set CasperJS page options from within a test in test environment?

Tags: javascript, automation, phantomjs, casperjs

I run most of my CasperJS tests with the `test` command as well as the 
`--ssl-protocol=any`and  `--ignore-ssl-errors=true` flags.

Is there a way that I can add those 2 flags to the tests themselves if they're in the test environment? I know you can set page options if you use the casper module like `var casper = require('casper').create({`, but that's not how my tests are set up.

I also know you can do stuff like

```
casper.options.verbose = true;
casper.options.logLevel = "debug";
```

...but `casper.options.ignoreSslProtocol=true` doesn't seem to work.

here's part of my login test --

```
var config = require('../../config'),
    x = require('casper').selectXPath;

casper.test.comment('basic login test!');
casper.start(config.base_url);
casper.test.begin('test basic login functionality', function (test) {

    casper.then(function() {
       this.click('.js-flip_box');
       test.info('logging in');
       this.fill('#login_form', {
            'email': config.email,
            'password': config.password
        }, true);
    });

    casper.then(function () {
        test.assertVisible ('.home_bar', 'nav bar visible');
    });

    casper.run(function() {
        test.done();
    });

});
```

...which I run with `casperjs --ssl-protocol=any --ignore-ssl-errors=true test login.js` (a mouthful)

am I doomed?

Comment: You really should be moving `casper.start()` inside of `casper.test.begin()` otherwise you will experience undefined behavior when you add another `casper.test.begin()` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, because PhantomJS doesn't provide such an option, but it should be really easy to add it to the code base as a pull request.

If you don't want to edit the source code and compile it yourself, then you can use the next best thing which is the `--config=config.json` option where you can define such options instead of defining them on the commandline directly. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25311734) and [here](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/pull/140#issuecomment-1932850) for more information.

Example config.json:

```
{
    "ignoreSslErrors": true,
    "sslProtocol": "any"
}
```

See [here](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/1.9.8/src/config.h#L44-L65) for a full list of options.